# How to safely change CSP with Play Framework

Tags: playframework, content-security-policy

I have a web app in production with a CSP configured through Play Framework's application.conf as described at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/CspFilter

Now I want to make a change to my CSP, so I'd like to add a report-only CSP header that's just like my current enforce mode header except with the change I want to test out. That way I can make sure it won't break anything when I move it to enforce mode. I've done this with other web frameworks, but I can't figure out how to achieve this with Play framework.

Can someone explain how I can set up a second CSP with Play framework?

I tried putting this in my application.conf

```
    play.filters {
    ...snip...

      csp {
        reportOnly = false
        directives {
          ...snip...
        }
      }
    }

    play.filters.cspReportOnly = ${play.filters.csp} {
      reportOnly = true
      directives {
        require-trusted-types-for = 'script'
      }
    }
```

But I only get the enforce mode CSP header. I don't get a report-only CSP header.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do. Will you have different configurations for different servers (local, test, prod, etc) and want to apply different policies? Could you provide details about both use cases you want to cover? maybe some requests and respones expected? could be possible a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have a CSP in prod that was fine. But now I want to enhance the CSP by using trusted types. But I don't want to just throw trusted types into an enforce mode because I don't know if it will break the app. So I want a report-only CSP that is the enforce mode one plus trusted types. Then I'll know if trusted types would break things or if I can just turn on trusted types.